# How to create an dictionary from array and list in python?

Tags: python

```
keys = ["x","y","z","x*x","2*y","2*z+3*x*x","w"]
values = [[0.00221024, 0.00289774, 0.00362644, 0.00222213, 0.00289774, 0.00243777, 0.00346482]]
dict_values = dict(zip(keys,zip(*values)))
```

output:

```
{'x' : (0.00221024,)
'y' : (0.00289774,)
'z' : (0.00362644,)
'x*x' : (0.00222213,)
'2*y' : (0.00289774,)
'2*z+3*x*x':('0.00243777,')
'w' : (0.00346482,)}
```

Excepted Output:

```
{'x' : 0.00221024,
'y' : 0.00289774,
'z' : 0.00362644,
'x*x' : 0.00222213,
'2*y' : 0.00289774,
'2*z+3*x*x': 0.00243777,
'w' : 0.00346482,}
```

I tried dict and zip function but can anyone explain how to write a loop or any logic to match with the excepted output.

Comment: Please add code, output of the code and error messages as a properly formatted text to your question, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Why are you using zip twice?

Comment: Not a machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: If my answer is useful, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict(zip(keys,values[0]))
```

output:

```
{'x': 0.00221024,
 'y': 0.00289774,
 'z': 0.00362644,
 'x*x': 0.00222213,
 '2*y': 0.00289774,
 '2*z+3*x*x': 0.00243777,
 'w': 0.00346482}
```

values is a list of lists with only one element, so you have to select the first list (`values[0]`).

`zip()` function creates an iterator that aggregates elements from two or more iterables. In your case, you have to use it only once.